# Can we construct Cantor set by any integer which is strict bigger than 2.

Tags: cantor-set

As we also know, the normal Cantor set is constructed by keeping cutting out the middle 1/3 set.

So, can we construct a Cantor set $E$ by keeping cutting out the nth 1/m set, where $1 \leq  n \leq m$, $m >2$ are integers.
It means that we can not only cut the middle set, but also the first set or the last set when $m=3$.

Moreover, $E$ will keep the properties that the normal Cantor set has.

(i) $E$ is uncountable.

(ii) $E$ has zero measure.

(iii) $E$ is nowhere dense.

The above there properties are easy to prove. Do I lose any important property that $E$ may have?

Comment: It won't have measure zero. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: @freakish In my construction, in every step, the ratio I cut off is a constant.